# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke exception in iisexpress.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, opencv, iis, emgu

Я использую надстройку над opencv для языка C# EMGU: 3.1.0.2282 в своем ASP.NET MVC5 проекте. А конкретнее я от туда беру библиотеку **Emgu.CV.World** (делаю ссылку на нее в проекте, сама она лежит в другой директории в каталоге EMGU папке bin). И папку x86, со сборками cv, опять же из каталога bin.

При запуске метода, кот. обращается к CvInvoke.Threshold () от EMGU, происходит ошибка:

> "An exception is thrown at 0x2AF630B1 (cvextern.dll) in
>   iisexpress.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x00000000."

Что важно, этот проект с этими же библиотеками запускался ранее без ошибок, возможно нарушилась какая-то связь со сборками, однако все что я делал это - скопировал этот же проект в эту же директорию, но с др. названием папки в кот. он находится, запустил его и получил эту ошибку, после этого и предыдущий проект стал ее выдавать.

Для тестирования был создан проект WindowsForms с этим же функционалом и теми же библиотеками, ошибок не выдает.

Пробывал добавлять к проекту папку x64, менять настройки запуска (Any cpu, x86, x64), все тщетно.

IIS Express 10, vs 2015 community.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ все-таки найден. Виной ошибки стала не замеченная во время последнего рефакторинга строка: `imgGray.Dispose();`

```
imageRotate = imgGray.Rotate(-avg, new Gray(255));
        }
        else
        {
            imageRotate = imgGray;
        }
        imgGray.Dispose();

        //return imageRotate.Bitmap;
        return BlackFilterImage(imageRotate);
    }

    private static Bitmap BlackFilterImage(Image<Gray, byte> img)
    {
        UMat resultImg = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Threshold(img, resultImg, 105, 255, ThresholdType.BinaryInv); //Ошибка возникала тут
```

К сожалению характер ошибки повел меня изначально по ложному следу.